# Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and let $M=\sup_{ a \leq x \leq b} |f(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and let $M=\sup_{ a \leq x \leq b} |f(x)|$.

$(i)$  If $M>0$ and $p$ be any positive constant, show that for every $ \epsilon>0$ there are constant $ c<d$ so that $ [c,d] \subset [a,b]$ and

$$ (M-\epsilon)^p (d-c) \leq \int_a^b |f(x)|^pdx \leq M^p(b-a) .$$

$(ii)$ Prove that $ \ \lim_{p \to \infty} \left(\int_a^b |f(x)|^pdx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$

**Answer:**

$(i)$

Since $ M=\sup_{ a \leq x \leq b} |f(x)|$, we have $ \ |f(x)| \leq M$.

Thus,

$ \int_a^b |f(x)|^pdx \leq M^p \int_a^b dx=M^p(b-a), ............(1)$.

Also since $ M=\sup_{ a \leq x \leq b} |f(x)|$, by definition of supremum, we have

$M-\epsilon \leq |f(x)|$.

Also suppose that $ M-\epsilon$ value is attained in the subset $[c,d]$, then

$ \int_a^b |f(x)|^p dx \geq \int_c^d |f(x)|^pdx \geq (M- \epsilon)^p \int_c^d dx=(M-\epsilon)^p (d-c), ............(2)$.

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$ (M-\epsilon)^p (d-c) \leq \int_a^b |f(x)|^pdx \leq M^p(b-a)$.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

Also help me with part $(ii)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that $M-\epsilon$ must be attained at some point. For example if $f\equiv M$ then $M-\epsilon$ is not attained. The correct argument is as follows: there exists $x$ such that $|f(x)| >M-\epsilon$. By continuity there exists an interval $[c,d]$ around $x$ on which $|f| >M-\epsilon$. Now proceed as you have done. This gives i). For ii) simply raise all sides of the inequality in i) to power $\frac 1 p$ and take the limit. Use the fact that $t^{1/p} \to 1$ as $p \to \infty$ for any $t>0$. (Use this for $t=d-c$ and $t=b-a$). By sandwich theorem you get ii).